# Engine cut out whilst driving. VSA and engine management lights came on

Tags: electrical

On my Honda Civic 2006 1.4 Whilst driving my engine cut out and at first my VSA light came on followed shortly after by the engine management light. the engine would still turn over but wouldnt fire up. its been in the garage but they can not find the fault. A few B code readings came up but the garage couldnt find the problem. Could be the ECU they said

Comment: Get another opinion. Any shop worth their salt can diagnose it, don't let them throw parts at it.

Comment: What were the B (body) codes?  Possibly the security interlock crapped out.  @Moab is right; find a better shop.  I doubt it's the ECU.  The injectors and ignition are not firing, likely because the ECU is being told not to.

Comment: the B codes were B1168, B1241, B1240, B1235.  and a reading 5610 (said internal failure of SRS unit. Thanks for your help

Comment: Ive just talked to the mechanic and he said he thinks the problem lies with the earth side of the wiring which could be faulty anywhere in the system